# Using "of" in describing something

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

I am trying to help my girlfriend study english.

She was wondering why use *"of"* in the following sentence:

> The Chinese self-image is still in so many ways, **of** a weak country.

Is it simply a more formal way of describing something which must be learned by rote, or is there a grammar rule I can explain to clarify it?

Comment: There is nothing unusual at all about the *of* in the sentence. Try to read it simplified by dropping the parenthetical: "The Chinese self-image is still (that) of a weak country" -- *that* can and usually is omitted where it is safe to do so.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

An image is not a country, which is what you say if you omit *of*:

> The Chinese self-image is . . . a weak country.

We ordinarily say that we have an image (a picture) *of* something. In this case it's complicated by the use of ***self***-image; the literal sense of the sentence is that

> The Chinese image of themselves is [an image] of a weak country.

It would be more rational to say that

> China's image of itself is [an image] of a weak country.

But this sort of conflation of the country and its people, like that of an organization and its members, is pretty standard.

Comment: How about using "that"  ("is that of a weak...")?

Comment: @Centaurus That would be fine; the referent of *that* would be *an image*, so it amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

"Of" indicates belonging. So in the example sentence given, the assumption is that weak countries have certain shared characteristics, and the Chinese self-image is then suggested to be from that class of shared characteristics.